# How to add multiple hyperlinks to email body from Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, outlook-2010

I have been googling for an answer for this for 2 weeks now I have clicked on every link there is maybe I am not asking the right way.
In `Sheet17.Range("AC" & Lastrow & ":" & "AM" & Lastrow)` I have some hyperlink address not all of those cells are filled
I am trying to get these address into my email body as separate clickable link.
I would love to have the name only but would be happy for the link.

This is my email body

```vb
   xStrBody = "Hi there:" & NRes & "<br>" _
                & emailfrm.Body & "<br>" _
         & "Click <a href=""https://form.jotform.com/202217530090846"">here</a> to ..."
```

This works for the one I have hardcoded but I don't know how to get the ones from the cells in there.
At this stage I am prepared to change my worksheet to  make it easier to get the links in the email even if I have to put in another separate  worksheet

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Dim c As Range, lnk, nm

xStrBody = "Hi there:" & NRes & "<br>" & emailfrm.Body & "<br>" 

for each c in Sheet17.Range("AZ2:AZ" & Lastrow).Cells
    nm = c.value
    lnk = c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "BA").Value
    
    xStrBody = xStrBody & "<a href=""" & lnk & """>" & nm & "</a><br>"

next c
```

Comment: Oh my goodness Thank you so much after weeks looking you have done it. Do you know how to get the name in there say if I saved the links in a range ("AZ2"BA" and last row). with the name in AZ and the link address in BA.

Comment: You are wonderful. it works it really works. How do I get just the name to show and not the link so they click on the name and it takes you there

Comment: Also is there a voting button because you desirve a medal as I have been trying for such a long time

Comment: It doesn't already show the name (from Col AZ) ?   The link (from Col BA) should not be shown, since it's just in the href...

Comment: It comes out like this Hi there:5 Star Admin Limited
I am so happy that this runs
Home office
https://form.jotform.com/202264723287052
New Client
https://form.jotform.com/202217530090846
Home office
https://form.jotform.com/202264723287052
New Client
https://form.jotform.com/202217530090846

Comment: Its not repeating its self there actually 4 links in email from my list

Comment: I got it I changed to this nm = c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "BC").Value and it works I am so Happy thank you thank you

Comment: Good to see you figured it out

Comment: What I can not figure out because this is the first time I have used HTML is I would like a couple of spaces inbetween "Hi there:" & NRes and my body is also Taken from a textbox on my form but when it comes out in the email it is one long sentence how do I get emailfrm.Body to come out as typed

Comment: If you want to translate plain text to HTML a good first step would be to replace chr(10) with `<br>` - that will at least give you line breaks in your message

Comment: I dont have any Chr(10) the rest of the email body comes from a textbox on a form and I do ctrl enter to start another line

Comment: This is my body  xStrBody = "Hello," & "    " & NRes & "<br>" & emailfrm.Body & "<br>" the bit after Hello does not put a space .

Comment: Can I do a mixture of HTML and VBA ?

Comment: If you want more than one space you need to use something like "&nbsp;&nbsp;" - HTML will collapse multiple spaces to a single space.   Not sure what you mean by a mixture of VBA and HTML - they are two different things: one is a programming language  and the other is not.

Comment: I got it so excited AdaptedText = Replace(emailfrm.Body.Text, vbCrLf, "<br>")

xStrBody = "Hello," & "    " & NRes & "<br>" & AdaptedText & "<br>"

Comment: `xStrBody = "Hello, " & " " & NRes & "<br>" & Replace(emailfrm.Body, Chr(10), "<br>") & "<br>"`